# how to find all same values in multiple columns with one query

Tags: mysql, multiple-columns

how to summarize and sort all distinct values im multiple columns? I have a table with 3 columns in it, and want to count all unique values of all rows which occur in thesse 3 columns: worp1,worp2,worp3

For one column it's working with this query:

```
'''

SELECT 
    worp1, 
    COUNT(worp1) c
FROM
    logfile
GROUP BY worp1
order by c

'''
```

What I wantas output:

```
worp123  |count
T20      |20
T19      |18
20       |15
....
T11      |0
```

sample data:

```
datum, speler, worp1,worp2,worp3
2019-05-07 23:50:46, 3, 1, T20, 0
2019-05-07 23:51:21, 1, 3, 7, 19
2019-05-07 23:51:34, 2, 5, T1, 20
2019-05-07 23:51:55, 3, 25, 25, D25
2019-05-07 23:52:28, 1, 1, 1, 12
2019-05-07 23:52:38, 2, 20, 20, 18
2019-05-07 23:53:03, 3, 1, 16, 2
2019-05-07 23:53:42, 1, 3, 19, 19
2019-05-07 23:53:53, 2, T5, 5, 5
2019-05-07 23:54:30, 3, 3, 10, 0
2019-05-07 23:54:59, 1, 19, T19, 20
2019-05-07 23:55:11, 2, 1, 5, 4
2019-05-07 23:55:30, 3, 17, 6, 25
2019-05-07 23:56:00, 1, 5, 7, 20
2019-05-07 23:56:07, 2, 20, 20, 20
2019-05-07 23:56:38, 3, 16, 15, 7
2019-05-07 23:57:11, 1, 7, 7, 19
2019-05-07 23:57:26, 2, 1, 5, 20
2019-05-07 23:57:43, 3, 2, 17, 17
2019-05-07 23:58:36, 1, T16, 4, 0
2019-05-07 23:58:43, 2, 4, 12, 20
2019-05-07 23:59:03, 3, 9, T20, 5
2019-05-07 23:59:40, 1, 0, 0, 0
2019-05-07 23:59:45, 2, 18, 20, 0
2019-05-08 00:00:14, 3, T1, 1, 20
2019-05-08 00:00:47, 1, 0, 0, 0
2019-05-08 00:00:54, 2, 6, 0, 0
2019-05-08 00:01:26, 3, T20, D14
```

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: update your question and add  a coherent data sample  ..

Answer (score 0):

Their may be a more efficient way to do it, but I think this would work for you:

```
SELECT worp, SUM(cnt) FROM (
    SELECT worp1 AS worp, COUNT(worp1) AS cnt FROM logfile GROUP BY worp1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT worp2 AS worp, COUNT(worp2) AS cnt FROM logfile GROUP BY worp2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT worp3 AS worp, COUNT(worp3) AS cnt FROM logfile GROUP BY worp3
) a
GROUP BY worp
```

Comment: Is not working: mysql returns "Every derived table must have its own alias"

Comment: Oh, sorry. After that last `)`, add anything. A single letter would work.

Comment: Thanks a thousand times, that works! You saved me a lot of time my friend!